# How do I select option from a Select Listbox dynamically during runtime ? Selenium_Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a select listBox of around 10 elements containing account no. with balance. These balances change sometimes they go to zero some time they have some amount, what I want to do is select the option at runtime which has a positive account balance.
The format of the text in LB is :
Acc no. (INR 12345 :SomeText)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share HTML code for the same. also if any code you've tried.

Comment: 1. get your select as WebElement. 2. click it to make it's options reachable. 3. get all options as child elements. 4. click desired option.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. load select option
2. get select option xpath
3. then get all the text reside in the option element
4. Then you logic

   ```
     List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.findElements(optionXpath);
     List<String> optionHasMoreMoney = new ArrayList<String>();

           for(WebElement eachEle: allOptions){
               long amount = Long.parseLong(eachEle.getText());
               if(amount > 0){
                   optionHasMoreMoney.add(eachEle.getText());
               }
           }


           // list of options which has more money
           Select select = new Select("your select element");
           select.selectByValue(optionHasMoreMoney.get(0));
   ```